# What is the best way to reach Paris Orly airport from Rue Mirabeau?

Tags: france, routes

Well I am in dilemma. I am not French citizen and have to catch a flight tomorrow at 13:25 France time. I intend to reach there by 12.

What is the best way to reach Paris Orly airport from Rue Mirabeau?

Comment: This type of question often gets closed because what do you mean by "best"? Is price or time a factor? Does best mean the fastest or the cheapest, etc.?

Comment: Here is a (commercial) [guide](https://www.welcomepickups.com/paris/orly-airport-to-city/) for the *reverse* direction, if that helps.

Comment: You'll need to know in advance which terminal you depart from (1, 2, 3 or 4).

Comment: Of course, we are guessing that you mean rue Mirabeau in Paris. There are plenty of other "rue Mirabeau" in many other towns in the Paris area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Best as in "simplest, most convenient": call a taxi. It'll take anywhere between 20 and 50 minutes depending on traffic, and will cost you 39 to 42 euros (35 euros flat fee Paris Right Bank to Orly + 4 or 7 euros booking fee). Alternatively, Uber, LeCab, Chauffeur Privé, etc. (prices vary). Taxis have the advantage of being able to use bus lanes, but that should make little difference on this specific route.
- A few public transport options:

  - **Line 10** to La Motte-Piquet – Grenelle, **Line 6** to Denfert-Rochereau, **Orlybus** to Orly. 1.90 € (Metro) + 8.30 € (Bus) = 10.20 €.
  - **Line 10** to La Motte-Piquet – Grenelle, **Line 6** to Denfert-Rochereau, **RER B** to Anthony, **Orlyval** to Orly. 12.10 €
  - **Line 10** to Cluny-La Sorbonne, **RER B** to Anthony, **Orlyval** to Orly. 12.10 €
  - **Line 10** to La Motte-Piquet – Grenelle, **Line 6** to Montparnasse, **Le Bus Direct Line 1** to Orly. 1.90 € (Metro) + 12.00 € (Bus) = 13.90 €.
  - **Line 10** to Jussieu, **Line 7** to Villejuif – Louis Aragon, **Line T7** to Orly. 1.90 € (Metro) + 1.90 € (Tram) = 3.80 €. Cheapest but longest (close to 1h30, while the other options are in the 50-70 minutes range).